DPDK-Pktgen get Segment Fault on various Testsetups
I am a little bit stuck right now so I really could need some help.
I want to create a Flask interface to create and send pcaps. The create part is done with Scapy and works without problems. To send packets I want to read the created Pcap-file and use dpdk-pktgen aiming to get roughly 10G.
My problem is, that pktgen just wont work and I cant wrap my head around what I am doing wrong.
I have a test setup in EVE-NG using ubuntu-22.04, I emulate an Intel-Skylake-Server CPU and the machine has 3 ports, 1 for management, 2 for traffic.
I tried installing the newest pktgen and dpdk version, currently pktgen: 24.05.3 and dpdk: 24.07.0-rc0. But I got numerous errors compiling pktgen. After numerous attempts I switched to pktgen: 22.04.01 and dpdk: 22.11.1 following the tips from this thread.
Now I could compile pktgen, and I can start pktgen with:
sudo ./path/to/pktgen -l 0-1 -- -P -s 0:myfile.pcap

In the now open console I tried to use "str" but no traffic is generated.
What do I need to change, to generate traffic and is it possible to start the transmission without the console, so that only one command is needed?
Since I didnt want use an outdated version of dpdk and pktgen I tried to use the newest ones.
On Ubuntu-22.04 I only got compiling errors, so i switched to ubuntu-23.10. This fixed my compiling errors, but despite using the same setup as in ubuntu-22.04 I either get:
Pktgen got a Segment Fault
Obtained 7-8 stack frames
or:
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
Cause: pktgen_pcap_open: rte_zmalloc_socket() failed for pcap_info_t structure
I used the exact same Pcap-file and I don't find anything for this error online.
I also tried to avoid EVE-NG, I thought maybe the emulation might be a problem. I tried ubuntu-23.10 and ubuntu-24.04 on my personal computer, but I got the same errors.
It might be important, my personal computer is running an AMD-Ryzen 5 5600X.
Also worth mentioning: I use the uio_pci_generic kernel. In EVE-NG I dont have IOMMU groups, even after changing the grub I still dont have any so I cant use the vfio-pci kernel. Same for my personal computer, but here my mainboard is the problem, since it wont split my IOMMU groups and I cant seperate my networkcard.
Can someone help me to achieve my above mentioned goal? Are there other tools out there, that could easily read and send traffic of a pcap and generate a lots of traffic?
I appreciate every single bit of help.
Sincerely

Although the main focus of the question is the issue with pktgen, it seems to allow for a different solution using some "other tools", hence the below answer.
In DPDK, there is a virtual device driver named pcap. Among other features, it allows one to read packets from a pcap file the way that they appear on the virtual device's Rx queue as if they have just arrived from wire. With option infinite_rx=1, it is possible to instruct the driver to repeat the replay continuously. Given that, it should be possible to attach such a device so that it provides packets to be forwarded to another device, for example, to a physical one. As a forwarder application, one may use l2fwd, a sample program shipped with DPDK, or, when more controls are needed, test-pmd.
Here's an approximate workflow description to get this working:
sudo apt update

sudo apt install git libnuma-dev libpcap-dev meson ninja-build python3-pyelftools
# (one also has to care about dependencies for the physical NIC driver, if any)

git clone https://dpdk.org/git/dpdk
cd ./dpdk

meson -Dexamples=l2fwd build
ninja -C build

# Instead of 0000:02:00.0, one should query the
# actual physical NIC port's PF ID via command
# sudo ./usertools/dpdk-devbind.py --status

# To configure 1G hugepages, one may use command
# sudo ./usertools/dpdk-hugepages.py --setup=1G

# For l2fwd, the command is as follows:
sudo ./build/examples/dpdk-l2fwd --vdev net_pcap0,rx_pcap=/path/to/file.pcap,infinite_rx=1 -a 0000:02:00.0 -- -p 0x3

# For test-pmd, one may launch forwarding either via single command
sudo ./build/app/dpdk-testpmd --vdev net_pcap0,rx_pcap=/path/to/file.pcap,infinite_rx=1 -a 0000:02:00.0 --
# or using the interactive test-pmd prompt, as follows
sudo ./build/app/dpdk-testpmd --vdev net_pcap0,rx_pcap=/path/to/file.pcap,infinite_rx=1 -a 0000:02:00.0 -- -i
# testpmd> set fwd io
# testpmd> start
# testpmd> show port stats all
# testpmd> stop

Once forwarding has been started, the pcap device will continuously "receive" the packets from the file and such will be forwarded to the Tx queue of the physical NIC port, ending up on the wire.
Should the pcap driver complain about multi-segment packets, one may want to first drop the infinite_rx=1 argument from device options just to make sure that at least something can work and then consider collecting a pcap file with smaller packets so that a packet can always fit in a single mbuf. Alternatively, when using test-pmd, one may want to specify --mbuf-size=X option (after the -- separator) that is supposed to set mbuf data room size to the desired value of X.
Whether this setup can hit the 10G line rate or not is a different topic that belongs in a separate question.
